# Using epsfig - gives errors in Kile but compiles fine using pdflatex in terminal

Tags: eps, kile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epsfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \epsfig{file=example.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When I compile with PDFLaTeX in Kile (I compile three times at least), I get an error each time that says "finished with exit code 1" and absolutely nothing else in the log. If I go to the terminal (I'm on Mac OS) and do `pdflatex example.tex`, then it compiles. And if I go back to the Kile editor and try to compile it again, it works after this!

Any have some insight here? It's a bit bizarre but not a huge deal since I'm getting it to compile in the end anyway...

Comment: have you tried using the `epstopdf` package?

Comment: pdflatex can not include eps files you need to convert it to pdf, also the `epsfig` package is for compatibility with LaTeX 2.09, don't use it unless your document was written in the 1980s use the `graphicx` package instead.

Comment: Has this problem been resolved?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are doing: as mentioned, pdfLaTeX can't use EPS graphics directly although more up-to-date setups do auto-conversion. In any case, more detail (_e.g._ log files) will be needed to solve this.