# Using epsfig in lncs guidelines

Tags: graphics, pdftex, lncs

In the [template for the Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip) the guideline PDF states:

> Preferably the images should be enclosed as PostScript files – best as EPS data using the `epsfig` package.

My question is simply "are they serious about this?" From what I know, `epsfig` is an old package and it is better to use `graphicx` instead. [I have even found comments on this very page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115810/using-epsfig-gives-errors-in-kile-but-compiles-fine-using-pdflatex-in-terminal) that it is better to use `graphicx`.

I usually use the pdfLaTeX compiler for my writing as it most directly gives me what I want. I now have two questions for you:

1. In your experience, is it really necessary to use EPS images? It is much easier to use PDFs and use pdfLaTeX than making EPS  files and going to PDF via PS.
2. Is it really necessary to use the ancient `epsfig` package?

Comment: No, they aren't serious.

Comment: @egreg So in your experience, posting a document compiled with `pdfLatex` using `pdf` files and the `graphicx` package with the `pdftex` option is OK?

Comment: I think that they didn't update the manual; requiring DVI output in 2010 seems quite bizarre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`epsfig` in its current form isn't actually ancient. It was written at same time as `graphicx` but it is emulating the much older latex2.09 package of the same name. Its behaviour is identical to `\includegraphics` — just a small syntax change:

```
\epsfig{file=foo,a=b,x=y}
```

becomes

```
\includegraphics[a=b,x=y]{foo}
```

There is no reason at all to use `epsfig`, unless processing documents from the 1980's (if the publisher really insists on it, it probably doesn't do any harm, it's just a silly restriction)

As for whether *you* need to use EPS, that depends on the publisher, often they have specific requirements for their production systems that are not obvious when you just look at the author submission form.

Comment: I've recently read answers by you in which you vehemently tell people "do not load `epsfig`" (I didn't actually know about the package until I saw you say this). In one of them, you say that "the `epsfig` latex package has been obsolete for 20 years" (which feels pretty ancient). Yet in the `graphics` manual (from 2014/04/27) there is no mention of this (ie, that you shouldn't load `epsfig`) at all. Shouldn't this recommendation be in the manual as well? I thought it was odd that the manual said nothing about it.

Comment: @jja the `graphics` manual isn't really from 2014, apart from a minor tweak or two, it is from the same period. `epsfig` `graphics` and `graphicx` were all written at the same time, but as it notes in its own documentation `epsfig` is simply a wrapper around `graphicx` to allow people to switch easily to latex2e while preserving the syntax of the old latex209 `epsfig` and `psfig` packages. Updating LaTex2.09 documents was a major concern then, I wasn't expecting the package to be still of use 20 years later:-)

Comment: @jja `texdoc grfguide` intentionally doesn't mention `epsfig` at all apart from a small listing at the end. The documentation for `epsfig` is obtained by `texdoc epsfig.pdf` and the documentation _in full_ is: emulate epsfig.sty and most varieties of psfig.  So if you are not needing that emulation, don't use it!

Comment: Sure. I definitely won't. :) The only reason I asked was because when I wrote `texdoc epsfig` I expected to see some sort of explanation about why it shouldn't be loaded. I thought it was weird that it wasn't there even though the manual was recent. Thanks for clearing that up.